# Como redireccionar a una pantalla distinta desde un pop up en Genexus 16

Tags: modal, eventos, genexus, popup

estoy trabajando en Genexus 16 y necesito redireccionar a una nueva pantalla desde un evento disparado en un botón que se encuentra en una ventana modal. El problema esta en que al disparar el evento, genexus continua la ejecución de las pantallas dentro de la misma ventana modal. ¿Existe alguna manera de evitar ese comportamiento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es abrir un objeto en una nueva pestaña desde el PopUp, lo puedes hacer con JavaScript. Debes agregar un Textblock que tenga Format = HTML. Luego, en el evento que quieres que se abra el objeto en la nueva pestaña agregas el siguiente código:

```
Textblock.Caption = '<script>window.open("' + ObjetoALlamar.Link(&Parametro1, 
&Parametro2,...,&ParametroN) + '","Pagina Nueva");</script>'
```

Si lo que quieres es ejecutar cierto código cuando se cierre el PopUp, en el evento del PopUp pones return, y en el evento del llamador del PopUp pones lo siguiente:

```
Event 'Llama a POPUP'
  &LlamoAPopUp(variable boolean) = true
  ObjetoPopUp.Popup()
  Refresh
EndEvent
```

Y en el evento Refresh del llamador del PopUp, el código que quieres que se ejecute:

```
Event Refresh
  If &LlamoAPopUp
     ObjetoALlamar.Call()
     &LlamoAPopUp = false
  EndIf
EndEvent
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Guido, ahora probare la solución. :D . Saluds

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el comando OpenNewWindow del Web Extension Toolkit (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?37807,Web+Extension+Toolkit).

En el nombre de la ventana debes poner "_parent" (https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-open-a-link-from-iframe-in-the-parent-window.html).